# postgres crosstab with unknown number of columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table test with looks like the following

[image]

That should be transformed to the following table
[image]

I can achieve that with the following `crosstab` statement

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab( 'select category, month, sum from test) AS ct(category text, r202208 float, r202209 float);
```

However this only works when I know the columns beforehand, but the table contains how much money I spend in each category and each month, so I don't know the months upfront. Is it possible to autogenerate the the columns based on the content in the month column of the original table, maybe by using a postgres function?

Of course I could generate the sql query dynamically as string and execute it with java, node or something else. However I get the data as csv from my financial institute and the original table is just a view, so I would like to create that table without the help of external programming

Comment: No, not possible. SQL isn't really suited for this. Do this in your application when you _display_ the result.

Comment: Well, the view  *is* the display, however I now have a little script that writes the csv to database and creates the view dynamically with the actual query interpolated in the script. Certainly not the best solution and probably really bad performance, but for my use case it does the job.